# Is insincere idolatry permitted?

Tags: talmud-gemara, gentiles, avodah-zarah

The Talmud reports the following view about Gentiles who live outside Israel:

> דאמר רבי חייא בר אבא אמר רבי יוחנן גוים שבחוצה לארץ לאו עובדי עבודה זרה הן אלא מנהג אבותיהן בידיהן

These sages seem to be saying that the idolatry of most Gentiles does not count because they do so only out of sense of tradition rather than a sincere devotion to alien gods. One wonders whether this is a special leniency for Gentiles (that insincere idolatry is in a sense permitted) or whether these sages would permit Jews who grew up in an idolatrous tradition to similarly participate in insincere idolatry?

Comment: Good question. It would still likely be forbidden because of Chukat Goyim.

Comment: You seem to be conflating two different things: 1) whether or not people who worship idolatry merely because they were raised to do so (and whose worship is therefore less devout and more by habit, see Rashi and Tosafos) have the status of idolators in certain regards, and 2) whether or not the idolatrous actions they do are permitted.

Comment: Surely an act of worship is either idolatry or not idolatry and there is no room for middle ground?

Comment: מאהבה ומיראה מחלוקת אביי ורבא

Comment: @Fred How is it possible to divorce the act from the actor? If an act is idolatry, the actor must be an idolator otherwise we would be in an absurd circumstance of an act with no agent.

Comment: @kouty One wonders if idolatry based on love or fear is the equivalent of the insincere idolatry of tradition. If they are equivalent on further wonders why the Talmud never connected the love and fear question with the dictum of Johanan bar Nappaha dictum.

Answer (score 4):

In the Midrash we learn that Moses' grandson took up idolatry as a job, as it were.  King David was not pleased, so we can assume it is not permitted:

> One cunning fellow … asked him: “Why then do you sit here and serve [idols]?”
> He replied: “I am paid for it, but I despise it.”
> When [King] David heard of him he sent for him and said, “Do you, the grandson of so righteous a man practice idolatry?”
> He replied: “I have received this teaching from the house of my father's father [Moses]: Sell yourself to idolatry rather than be dependent on your fellow-creatures.”
> [David] said to him: “God forbid! That is not so.  What it means is: Sell yourself to a service which is foreign to you [i.e., which you consider to be below your dignity] rather than depend on your fellow-men.”  [Song of Songs Rabbah 2:18]

Comment: If cynical idolatry (that of Jonathan ben Gershom) is identical with traditional idolatry (that of people who worship because their ancestors did), how do we reconcile the midrash which condemns it with the Amoraim who permit it?

Comment: One is idolatry by inertia, without really giving it much thought, and that apparently can be tolerated; and the other is cynical idolatry, just to make a buck, and that apparently is not tolerated.

Comment: @MosheWise The Amoraim did not permit it ([*Shabbos* 72b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=72b&format=text), [*Sanhedrin* 61b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=61b&format=text)), but there is a *machlokes* about whether such a person is obligated to bring a *korban* if he insincerely worshipped idolatry because he **wrongly** thought it was permitted to worship idolatry insincerely (Rashi, *Shabbos* 72b: שגג בהכי דסבור כיון דאין מתכוין לבו לאלהות מותר). NB: Exempt and permitted are two different things.

Comment: @Fred The Johanan bar Nappaha dictum says neither 'permitted' nor 'exempt.' It simply that the traditional Gentile worshipers are not considered idolaters which means that their worship activity is not idolatry and is therefore not a violation of the prohibition of idolatry. If it is forbidden but not idolatry, it must be forbidden based on some other commandment or principle.